# PHP + cURL переход и вывод результата страницы

Tags: php, curl

Привет всем, подскажите пожалуйста)

Как сделать так чтобы скрипт переходил на страницу

```
http://football.ua/default.aspx?menu_id=search&search=$search
```

и выводил через **var_dump** результат поиска по переменной **$search?**
 Что может быть не так? заранее спасибо

Вот код

```
   $url = 'http://football.ua/';//URL к которому нужно обращаться
   $search = $_POST['search'];// значение из формы которое искать 

  $ch =curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");//все кодировки
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILNOERROR,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);//включение заголовков в вывод
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);//не проверять SSL сертификат
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);//не проверять HOST SSL
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');//сохранить куки в файл

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);//следования любому заголовку
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);//максимальное количество принимаемых   редиректов

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);

сurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.125 Safari/537.36 OPR/30.0.1835.88");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
"default.aspx?menu_id=search&search=$search" );


// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true );

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
//отслеживание ошибок
if($server_output === FALSE){
echo "cURL Error: " .curl_error($ch);
}
//получение инфо о cURL запросе
$info = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($info == 502 || $info == 503){
echo "Выпал код 502 или 503";
}

var_dump($server_output);
var_dump($search);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Так вы передаете параметры методом POST, а надо GET.
Попробуйте указать эти параметры в $url

Comment: @thecoder я новичок в курле) можете пример кода дать пожалуйста либо растолковать,заранее спасибо

Comment: попробуй вот так
$url = 'http://football.ua/default.aspx?menu_id=search&search=$search'

а строки

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
"default.aspx?menu_id=search&search=$search" );

закомментируй

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);

не маловат таймаут?
поставь 60

Comment: @thecoder  Спасибо большое за ответ)но почему то не работает( форма принимает значения но в поиске не выдает

Comment: напиши что у тебя в $search

Comment: домен http://football.ua блокируется провайдером
отсюда и проблема
У меня билайн.

Comment: @thecoder всё работает) нужно было переменную urlencode($search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все искомые слова на сайте проходят через функцию urlencode)

```
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    urlencode($search);// кодируем искомую строку из формы

  и всё работает)
```